# Use of functools.partial in a decorator that attaches function as attribute of object

Tags: python, decorator

In **Python Cookbook** section [9.5. Defining a Decorator with User Adjustable Attributes](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/python-cookbook-3rd/9781449357337/ch09s05.html) I've been having difficulty wrapping my head around the use of functools.partial in the following code:

```
# Utility decorator to attach a function as an attribute of obj
def attach_wrapper(obj, func=None):
    if func is None:
        return partial(attach_wrapper, obj)
    setattr(obj, func.__name__, func)
    return func
```

Is its use to prevent shadowing of attributes if composing multiple decorators? I am not totally clear to why partial would be used here and would appreciate any clarification.

Comment: it's not just attaching the function, it's attaching `f(obj, x,y)` as `obj.f(x,y)`. For this to work, `obj.f` has to pass itself as the first argument, while still allowing the user to pass the rest. `partial` is a very good way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll try two explanations. Here's the short one. These decorators are equivalent.

```
def attach_wrapper(obj, func=None):
    if func is None:
        return partial(attach_wrapper, obj)
    setattr(obj, func.__name__, func)
    return func


def my_attach_wrapper(obj):
    def wrapper(func):
        setattr(obj, func.__name__, func)
        return func
    return wrapper
```

And here's the long version. This is a step-by-step of what the wrapper does.

```
@attach_wrapper(wrapper)
def set_level(newlevel):
    level = newlevel
```

is equivalent to:

```
def set_level(newlevel):
   level = newlevel

set_level = attach_wrapper(wrapper)(set_level)
```

first, `attach_wrapper(wrapper, func=None)` returns a partial function that takes one argument, `func`. for simplicity, let's call this new function `partial_attach`. And we can define it like so:

```
def partial_attach(func):
    setattr(wrapper, func.__name__, func)
    return func
```

when `attach_wrapper(wrapper, func=None)` returns `partial_attach`, we have:

```
set_level = partial_attach(set_level)
```

since that returns `set_level`, `set_level` is equal to itself.  But now `wrapper` has an attribute, `set_level`, which points to the same function.